# How to prevent playback error YouTube iframe api

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I've been trying to work with the YouTube iframe api but I've noticed that sometimes it looks like it doesn't want to play any video, I get the following:

> An error occurred. Please try again later (Playback ID: XXX)

It doesn't happen all the time though, so far I assume it happens when I swap between Google/YouTube accounts...

Does anyone know how I can prevent / resolve this issue from happening?

Comment: with which `video_id`s you're trying? - please [edit] your question and add more details for understand and reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hey @MauricioAriasOlave it's not with any specific video_id, it happens with all videos, sometimes it just works fine but then the other moment I keep getting this error

Comment: It *might* be your page overrides or messes with the flow of scripts YouTube iframe loads in your page, or some related to your IP - maybe (*i'm not judging*) - there are many requests from your IP to YouTube and they (YT) decide to *just* stop the service to your specific webpage. I can't br sure. My suggestions are: check from another computer / IP or report this issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) - bear in mind, you have to provide enogh information for they can reproduce the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Alright thanks I'll see if I can find more, all I could find right now is that it usually seems to happen whenever I change accounts in Google or YouTube, which could make sense because I also notices that upon initializing the video player you also get "key" that's being used for the requests, not sure if this is per user or just for the whole website, but if its per user and you swap accounts it might not check for that and update the key

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561728/4092887) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269584/4092887) answer.