# WebOS web app won't show embedded youtube video

Tags: youtube, embedding, webos

I have a web application in which I embed a youtube video.

```
<object width="1152" height="648">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HOsOTaXUg7c">
    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HOsOTaXUg7c" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>
```

This code works perfectly in the browser, however on the WebOS simulator, the same code results in a `Video Unavailable`:

[image]

How to I make this video work on a WebOS TV?

Comment: Please try with another videos and even if all those tests fail, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561728/12511801) - I really don't know about WebOS, but, consider research if WebOS TV has some kind of restrictions to iframes or check therir forums/support for more info. I doubt if this is on-topic on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) - since is not about the YouTube Data API, but, it might be worth check that forum as well.

Comment: See my answer below. 
This issue is specific to the WebOS application architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in many cases, this issue is a result of either trying to embed a video that prevents a embedding or using the wrong youtube path, in this particular case, this behavior occurred because YouTube won’t allow embedding videos in a page with a `file://` protocol, which is the case for a basic WebOS app.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Use a [WebOS hosted app](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/getting-started/web-app-types#hosted-web-app)
2. Use a proxy iframe to load the video.

I created a [basic example of here](https://youtube-test.tiiny.site/?videoId=QwXHcgZUnFI) and it allows you to pass in a video ID and it will load it from any page.