# Is there any YouTube Data API field to check the availability of an embedded Video?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-data-api, embedding

I think there is one parameter missing checking the possibility of embedding a YouTube Video via Data API.

For example, this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3kWiFPXHsI&t=1s
If you can see: embedding is true:
[YouTube Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNDr5.png)

In an HTML Code Sandbox it's also available:
[Code Sandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVRc3.png)

But if I go to https://youtube.com/embed/K3kWiFPXHsI, the Video is unavailable:
[embed/VideoID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKGDK.png)

What's the reason for that?

I nearly tried everything regarding the API.

I also wrote a script that checks via
`curl -s https://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoID | grep "UNPLAYABLE" | wc -l`
the status flag.

The problem is that the video is also unavailable if i am not in the correct region.

I want to automate the hole process via Crawler. I need a solution to check this for every Region the video is available for. I hope you guys can help me. Thx

Comment: If you wanted to crawl this information for "every region", then you would probably need a VPN or a list of proxy servers, so that you can make your requests "from" those regions. (But public proxies are probably quite likely to get blocked after a while, when YT recognizes "automated" requests.

Comment: Going via API, and looking at properties such as `contentDetails.regionRestriction`, might be a more productive approach. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation

Comment: Hmmm, strange. I tested on jsfiddle and indeed, the video is playing there, but, not the direct embed URL on the browser. I though it was because region/copyright issues [as is shown on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561728/4092887), but, I guess it *might* be because the said channel has another *private* configuration on their channel - limiting the embedding of their videos and/or because the channel is a verified one and they have more features that *protects* their content...