# Video unavailable for embeddable video with open youtube license

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to detect, what kind of videos might be integrated to embedded player by the YouTube.
According to the google documentation, if the video has [embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) flag is `True`, it mean, that video might be integrated to [iframe player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

I tried to check this case with a lot of videos, but there is no correllation with official documentation:

```json
{
"kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
"etag": "QhZz3ammh_2U6Vc0CPEowhlDrww",
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "etag": "NHnhzMH_44LS8SvFmhtYF5jcKRk",
        "id": "GbfeH6Q8PzY",
        "status": {
            "uploadStatus": "processed",
            "privacyStatus": "public",
            "license": "youtube",
            "embeddable": true,
            "publicStatsViewable": true,
            "madeForKids": false
        }
    }
],
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
}
}
```

Above you might see info by video ID - embeddable with public youtube license.
And trying to open this video on the official embedded player: https://www.youtube.com/embed/GbfeH6Q8PzY How can I check what kind of video is possible to embed into a player?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71975098) solves your issue.

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72561728/4092887) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269584/4092887)